# Algolia Firestore Sync - Large Dataset - Rapid Changes

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, algolia

I am using Algolia for full text search of a Firestore collection.  It works very well, from a search prespective.

I am using Cloud Functions to sync the data - following the pattern found in many blog posts:  I use the Firestore `.onCreate()` `.onUpdate()` and `.onDelete()` hooks to prompt updates to the Algolia index.

e.g.

```
exports.update_products_index = functions.firestore.document('products/{productId}').onUpdate((change) => {
  const algolia_index = client.initIndex("products");
  const newData = change.after.data();
  const objectID = change.after.id;
  return algolia_index.saveObject({ ...newData, objectID });
});
```

This works fine with infrequent, individual updates, but falls over with frequent updates and/or batches (e.g. in a loop over all records in the collection).  This is a [known issue](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events):

> Cloud Firestore triggers for Cloud Functions is a beta feature with
> some known limitations:
>
> - It can take up to 10 seconds for a function to respond to changes in
> - Cloud Firestore. Ordering is not guaranteed. Rapid changes can trigger
>   function invocations in an unexpected order.

The new Algolia **[extension](https://www.algolia.com/blog/product/announcing-the-firebase-algolia-search-extension/)** for Firebase appears to use the [same pattern](https://github.com/algolia/firestore-algolia-search/blob/main/functions/src/index.ts):  Specifically, it utilizes Cloud Functions and the `.onWrite()` hook.
It also appears to be subject to the same limitations:  When I create and then almost immediately update around 3,000 documents, not all of the records are copied to my Algolia index and almost none of the updates are registered.

Is there a way to sync Algolia with a Firestore collection in these circumstances i.e. with frequent / rapid changes to large sets of data?  Or is there a way to throttle the process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there's no way to guarantee the order of execution, it's hard to find a to write this particular function. But I can think of a few work-around for the problem you have:

1. It sounds like you are only rapidly updating right after it's created? In that case maybe what can work is having your `create` write to a draft collection and have your `update` copy the updated data into the searchable collection.
2. Rather than updating, add new documents with timestamp and filter the result at query-time.
3. If your client can tolerate stale data, you can have a scheduled function that syncs all documents with Algolia.